# confused selected value in php

Tags: php

first, you would be asked to input/choose a Professor Number. then information of that professor would appear and there is a drop down for the subjects. but i want the subject under that professor would be the one selected in that select tag. 
this is for updating. therefore, the values shown are from the database.

i have this code in php

```
echo"<select name ='sub_code' >";

$res = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM arsy_subject ORDER BY arsy_sub_Code");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo("<option selected='$_POST[arsy_sub_Code]'  value = '" .$row['arsy_sub_Code']. "'>" .$row['arsy_sub_Code'] . "/" .$row['arsy_Description'] . "</option>");
}
```

Comment: Your question is confused, what's your issue?

Comment: well, I must have said I DON'T KNOW WHAT to do.. there are 5 options.. but I want to display as selected the 3rd option. how would I be able to do that? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are posting the `arsy_sub_Code` and want the selected value to remain selected. Try:

```
echo "<select name ='sub_code' >";

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arsy_subject ORDER BY arsy_sub_Code");

if($res && mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) // PLEASE check to make sure the query worked before trying to access rows
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $selected = isset($_POST['sub_code']) && $_POST['sub_code'] == $row['arsy_sub_Code'] ? 'selected' : '';

        echo "<option selected='$selected'  value = '" .htmlentities($row['arsy_sub_Code']). "'>" .htmlentities($row['arsy_sub_Code']) . "/" .htmlentities($row['arsy_Description']) . "</option>";
    }  
}

echo "</select>";
```

---

**Edit:**

If this is page that allows you to edit professor details, and you want the dropdown to show the professor's subject then you need to replace `$_POST['sub_code']` with your variable that contains the professor's current sub_code, so perhaps something along the lines of

```
$professor['sub_code']; // assuming you have selected the professor details and have stored them in an array
```

Obligatory side note: don't write new code in the deprecated `mysql_*` library, use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: hey MrCode. yes, the queries works well.  but still, the value I wanted to appear still don't appear. what always appear is the last value. :(

Comment: The selected option will be whatever `arsy_sub_Code` you POSTed...

Comment: how about the selected option will be whatever in the database is under the professor I have selected? :D

Comment: See my edit, your `<select>` is named `sub_code` so I think you need to reference that instead of `arsy_sub_Code`.

Comment: what does isset do? (sorry. I am really new to this. all I know are the very basics. we weren't taught, yet we were demanded to make a system. :( )

Comment: `isset()` checks if the variable is actually set or not. It should be used before trying to access `$_POST` and `$_GET` values because they may or may not be set. php.net has a reference for all functions, have a look there for more info.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17824/discussion-between-shi-na-and-mrcode)

Comment: @ShiNa have a look at my fix in the chat....

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make the selected row the row that has the same value as `$_POST[arsy_sub_Code]`???

Change the code to this one:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $selected=""; 

    if ($_POST[arsy_sub_Code]==$row['arsy_sub_Code']){
        $selected='selected="selected"'; 
    }

    echo("<option " . $selected . " value = '" .$row['arsy_sub_Code']. "'>" .$row['arsy_sub_Code'] . "/" .$row['arsy_Description'] . "</option>"); 
}
```

Comment: Denis Omeri, the value still don't appear. :( under the table arsy_subject, there is a field for professor(arsy_profNo) and subject code(arsy_sub_Code) because the query is executed, you could choose a profNo to update. and I want to show the subject under that professor.